# How to prevent uploaded file from being executed?

Tags: apache

How can i prevent uploaded file from being executed?
For example, someone could upload php file and use it to hack site, i want to prevent it.

Best that way that i know is using directory permissions, and set it to 666?

Is there some htaccess magic that i can do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just put a .htaccess in your upload folder with the following line :

`php_flag engine off`

It will disable PHP execution in this directory.

Edited to answer comments :
`chmod 666` does *not* prevent PHP execution. It simply marks files as *non-executable* so you can't run them directly as scripts or binaries. PHP does not care about the permissions of the file, as long as it is readable, it will get parsed and executed by the engine.

So if your server has multiple engines (PHP, Jelly, whatever) you will have to *manually* build a configuration file that will prevent files within a folder from being interpreted. You could make a script that would generate that file based on what engines are installed on the machine.

Comment: Yes, but i want to prevent all types of files from being executed.

Comment: I do not know, i am writing system which wont be used by me on my server, and may be potentially used on multiple servers.

Comment: How can i get list of running engines? And is there some reference on how to disable each engine? Searched apache docs didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2):

Permissions will not work if you modify them using FTP client and your server scripts are not using the same user/permissions (normal WordPress scenario).

If you want to avoid it with .htaccess, this may help.

Tested in **Litespeed server version 5.4.10**

```
<Files *.php>
deny from all
</Files>
```

```
<Files *.*>
deny from all
</Files>
```

```
<Files myfile.php>
deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: add versioning to which this applies because the question comes from the Stone Age!

Comment: Ups, I´m sorry, I checked this thread and others today trying to prevent WordPress from executing wrong theme files that are constantly updated from a remote server. 
.htaccess was the only working method.
I am not really sure what version should I detail. PHP version maybe?

Comment: Apache server version to which your script suggestion applies (and have tested). And whatever comes to mind relevant for this aged question.

Comment: Thank you! I edited my reply.
Server is Litespeed, so I hope the version number is enough. PHP or WP versions are not related to the original question, so I suposse that is all I can detail.